# eval() with a variable operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, eval

I'm Using Python 3.4. I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/GCSE's/Computing/Assesment/1/School Grading Script.py", line 44, in <module>
    if answer== eval(num1<currentop>num2):
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

when trying to execute this code

```
operator=["+","-","*"]
num1=random.randint(0,10)
num2=random.randint(0,10)
currentop=random.choice(operator)

answer = input("What is " + str(num1) + str(currentop) + str(num2) + "?\n")
if answer== eval(num1<currentop>num2):
    print("correct")
else:
    print(incorrect)
```

What I want to do is to check the answer against the randomly generated variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `eval` is really bad practice, and should be avoided. For what you are trying to do, you should be making use of [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

Change your data structure to use a dictionary to make it easier on you to perform your operations. Something like this:

```
import operator

operators = {
    "+": operator.add
} 

num1 = 4
num2 = 5

res = operators.get("+")(num1, num2)
```

Output of res:

```
9
```

To apply your random implementation in to this, you make use of the dictionaries `keys()` to do a `random.choice` on that:

```
random.choice(list(operators.keys()))
```

---

Simple example applying random:

```
import operator
import random

operators = {
    "+": operator.add,
    "-": operator.sub,
    "*": operator.mul
}

num1 = 4
num2 = 5

res = operators.get(random.choice(list(operators.keys())))(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `int`, `num1` and `num2` and `str`, `currentop`. Cast them to `str` and it would work:

```
if answer == eval(str(num1)+currentop+str(num2)):
```

PS: You should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/742269) using `eval()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a string, also "Incorrect" needs to be quoted:

```
import random
operator=["+","-","*"]
num1=random.randint(0,10)
num2=random.randint(0,10)
currentop=random.choice(operator)

answer = input("What is " + str(num1) + str(currentop) + str(num2) + "?\n")
if answer== eval(str(num1)+str(currentop)+str(num2)):
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

And as others have pointed out, unless for testing purposes, don't use eval.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the list of problems in your code:

1. `eval` is used with string variables.You should convert `num1` and
   `num2` as: `str(num1)` and `str(num2)`.
2. quote `incorrect`
3. also your variable `answer` contains string type of value as `input` returns    a string so u should cast `input` to `int`.

So after correcting all these the following code should work:

```
import random
operator=["+","-","*"]
num1=random.randint(0,10)
num2=random.randint(0,10)
currentop=random.choice(operator)

answer = int(input("What is " + str(num1) + str(currentop) + str(num2) + "?\n"))
if answer== eval(str(num1)+str(currentop)+str(num2)):
    print("correct")
else:
    print('incorrect')
```